# How to import a github gradle file to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, import

I want to import a github gradle file to my eclipse.

I'm trying to import a github gradle file to my eclipse. But it turns out to be many errors. I tried to import it as a regular file but it doesn't work as well. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether eclispe understands Gradle syntax. Therefore you have to install a Gradle Plugin for eclipse. You could check the Eclipse internal marketplace for that.
Once you installed the Gradle plugin and propably restarted Eclipse, you should be able to `IMPORT` a Gradle project by `loading / importing` the gradle file from the project.